# SQL Query: Retrieve list which matches criteria

Tags: sql

Sorry, I couldn't think of a better heading (or anything that makes sense).

I have been trying to write a SQL query where I can retrieve the names of student who have the same level values as student Jaci Walker.

The format of the table is:

```
STUDENT(id, Lname, Fname, Level, Sex, DOB, Street, Suburb, City, Postcode, State)
```

So I know the `Lname (Walker)` and `Fname (Jaci)` and I need to find the Level of Jaci Walker and then output a list of names with the same Level.

```
--Find Level of Jaci Walker
SELECT S.Fname, S.Name, S.Level
FROM Student S
WHERE S.Fname="Jaci" AND S.Lname="Walker"
GROUP BY S.Fname, S.Lname, S.Level;
```

I have figured out how to retrieve the Level of `Jaci Walker`, but don't know how to apply that to another query.

---

Thankyou to everyone for your help,
I'm just stuck on one little bit when adding the rest of the query into it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ws93pp1vk40awg/img.jpg

```
SELECT S.Fname, S.LName
FROM Student S, Enrollment E, CourseSection CS, Location L
WHERE S.S_id = E.S_id
AND E.C_SE_ID = CS.C_SE_id
AND L.Loc_id = CS.Loc_ID
AND S.S_Level = (SELECT S.S_Level FROM Student S WHERE S.S_Fname = "Jaci" AND S.S_Lname = "Walker")
AND CS.C_SE_id = (SELECT CS.C_SE_id FROM CourseSection CS WHERE ?)
AND L.Loc_id = (SELECT L.Blodg_code FROM Location L WHERE L.Blodg_code = "BG");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT S.Fname, S.Name, S.Level FROM Student s 
WHERE Level = 
(SELECT TOP 1 Level FROM Student WHERE Fname = "Jaci" and Lname = "Walker")
```

**If you don't use TOP 1, this query will fail if you have more than one "Jaci Walker" in your data.**

Comment: Then maybe it should fail, because the other Jaci Walkers can have different Levels ;-)

Comment: No, I would rather recommend you to expand your Where-Clause e.g. with city and suburb to make sure it's unique.

Comment: Ok, thankyou. I need to expand the query to include:
-People that have the same level, and
-People that have taken course with Jaci Walker in a particular building.

I just needed help starting it off after googling for days.

Comment: OK. Let me know if you need any further help with this query.

Comment: Hi @FabianBigler, I was wondering what I would put where the "?" is.

SELECT S.Fname, S.LName
FROM Student S, Enrollment E, CourseSection CS, Location L
WHERE S.S_id = E.S_id
AND E.C_SE_ID = CS.C_SE_id
AND L.Loc_id = CS.Loc_ID
AND S.S_Level = (SELECT S.S_Level FROM Student S WHERE S.S_Fname = "Jaci" AND S.S_Lname = "Walker")
AND CS.C_SE_id = (SELECT CS.C_SE_id FROM CourseSection CS WHERE ?)
AND L.Loc_id = (SELECT L.Blodg_code FROM Location L WHERE L.Blodg_code = "BG");

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ws93pp1vk40awg/img.jpg

Comment: I don't know your Database Schema. But you have to put something in there to receive the associated unique row.

Comment: @FabianBigler
I updated the first post with the database schema.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
SELECT S.Fname, S.Name, S.Level
FROM Student S
WHERE S.Level = 
    (SELECT Level
     FROM Student 
     WHERE Fname="Jaci" AND Lname="Walker"
    )
```

but you got to be sure to have only 1 student called Jaci Walker ...

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use your query as a subquery to find other entries with the same Level.

```
SELECT Fname, Name
FROM Student
WHERE Level = (
    SELECT Level FROM Student S WHERE S.Fname="Jaci" AND S.Lname="Walker")
```

Comment: Would you be able to help me with the next part of the query?

Comment: @JaciWalker you haven't phrased a question just posted a SQL query. In general questions shouldn't be widened afterwards. If your first question is answered accept an answer and start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to group your result.

Try this

```
Select Fname,Lname from Student 
where Level=(Select Level 
             from Student 
             where Fname='Jaci' AND Lname='Walker' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need group by and all for same...

Simply,

> ```
> SELECT S.Fname, S.Name, S.Level FROM Student S WHERE S.LEVEL LIKE (SELECT LEVEL FROM STUDENT WHERE Fname="Jaci" AND Lname="Walker");
> ```

Are you looking for same?